# Replacing Document in DocumentDB Not Saving Changes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I have a document that inherits from the Azure `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document` class, and this is the structure of my properties.

```
[JsonProperty("name")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("establishment")]
public string Establishment { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("description")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

I can save documents fine, however I am running into an issue when trying to update a document and replace it.

For example, if I were to do the following, the document's description never gets updated.

```
var project = documentRepository.FindById<ProjectDocument>("7fc2899e-4c7f-4c09-9f60-4ca28caca750");
project.Description = "Foo";
await documentRepository.Save(project);
```

However if I do this, then it does.

```
var project = documentRepository.FindById<ProjectDocument>("7fc2899e-4c7f-4c09-9f60-4ca28caca750");
project.SetPropertyValue("description", "Foo");
await documentRepository.Save(project);
```

Obviously I don't want to have to do this as it seems unneccessary.

It is worth noting that I am using my own library called `Documental` to use a repository pattern, but the underlying code is just calling the Azure DocumentDB library, i am having the same issues when directly using the DocumentDB library.

UPDATE: The runtime view of the object contains the correct value for the changed field as expected, but the Dynamic View of the object always contains its original value unless I use the `SetPropertyValue` method.

Comment: Did you try the ReplaceDocumentAsync method ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.replacedocumentasync.aspx

Comment: Yeah, so my library used to call ReplaceDocumentAsync but has since been replaced with UpsertDocumentAsync (https://github.com/tomeglenn/documental/blob/develop/Documental/Core/DocumentRepository.cs#L75)

However, I have also tried directly using documentClient.ReplaceDocumentAsync(document) but I get the same issue.

Comment: by any chance are you hitting this issue ? https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/132 also real update is not a feature and only replacing documents is happening internally https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document

Comment: Hi, no I don't think so as I have tried ReplaceDocumentAsync and encounter the same issue there.

Comment: maybe you should raise a bug report in the github page with all the details.

Comment: Looks like someone raised this on 5th April and there's been no response since. https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/117

Comment: Hmm .that's really not helping the cause here.guess you have to live with set property value for now.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the associated Github post that there seems to be a bug when extending classes from Document. Please extend from Resource as a base class and everything should work fine. You would then need to use the other overloads for ReplaceDocumentAsync that accept the docLink and the updated object.

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, example
You can use `**upsert**` that is available in document db API, which does all the dirty work for you and it replaces the document. you find details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.upsertdocumentasync.aspx)

Comment: At the time of posting this, that did not work. As @rajesh mentioned in his answer, there was a bug when inheriting from the Document class.

Comment: I am using this in my project and it works perfectly fine for me. When you update your app, you may wanna try again.